# PHP - Array_combine first row missing

Tags: php, arrays, explode, implode, array-combine

I have a problem with Array_combine function. I want to combine `prices` to set as `products` keys. First I get everything as string from html form. and use explode function make it array. this process for both. Here it is a short of code;

```
    $urunler = $_POST['urunler'];
    $fiyatlar = $_POST['fiyatlar'];
    $products = explode(",", $urunler);
    $prices = explode(",", $fiyatlar);
    $dizi_birlestir = array_combine($prices, $products);

// OUTPUT
   [15] => first,
   [25] => second

// EXPECTED OUTPUT
   [10] => first,
   [15] => second,
   [25] => third
```

Comment: Can show values of `$urunler` and `$fiyatlar`?

Comment: hi buddy. Sorry to see your reply now. I've solved the problem. It was occurs because of array_combine(); I've changed array_combine($prices, $products) to array_combine($products,$prices);